# How to cache from client side?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, client-side

I have done a keyword searching in asp.net mvc3 application. A textbox with autocompletion in server side is the main item here. But the problem is when 2 users working with same application will get the search result of the other one due to server side caching. Here is my server side coding..

```
function AutoComplete() {
    AccessService({ url: "/Home/AutoFill",
        type: "GET",
        asyncAction: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var inputArray = data.workOrderNos.split('ß');
            $('#txt_keyword').autocomplete({
                source: inputArray,
                minLength: 1
            });
        }
    });
}
```

In HomeController:

```
public JsonResult AutoFill()
        {
            string _workOrderNos = _iManagePropertyMaintenances.GetAllWorkOrderNumbers(); //Will retrieve all values

            return Json(new { workOrderNos = _workOrderNos }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

How can I do that autocompletion and searching through client side?? so that different users get the result of their own search criteria??

```
 private string UserViceSearchCriteriaName = "WorkOrderSearchCriteria" ;

 public ActionResult ViewWorkOrders(string criteria)
        {

    if (criteria != "")
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Cache[UserViceSearchCriteriaName] != null)
                        HttpContext.Cache[UserViceSearchCriteriaName] = criteria;
                    else
                        HttpContext.Cache.Add(UserViceSearchCriteriaName, criteria, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0), CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
                    ViewData["WorkOrderSearchCriteria"] = HttpContext.Cache[UserViceSearchCriteriaName].ToString();
                }
}
```

this way we are tracking the criteria (value in text box)

Comment: Are you sure Autofill is invoked twice on the server side while debugging for two different users ? Because it's maybe your browser that is just caching the user entry in the input field.

Comment: I have added some more in the code.. Hope this results in my issue..